# Cloud Sql Instance Promote with using shell

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to promote Cloud Sql Replica Instance to Primary while running script. At time one instance I can promote but I want to promote all available replicas to primary instance parallelly at the same time not one by one

please suggest correction in the script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set preject variables
gcloud auth login
read -p 'Please provide Project ID for the project that your instance is located in:' project
gcloud config set project $project

#Make a temp directory and file to store the JSON output from Gcloud
mkdir tempFiles
touch tempFiles/instanceDetails.json
touch tempFiles/instanceDetails-dr.json
touch tempFiles/replica1.json
touch tempFiles/replica2.json
touch tempFiles/replica3.json
touch tempFiles/replica4.json
touch tempFiles/replica5.json
touch tempFiles/primaryReplacementReplica.json

#Prompt the user for the primary instance and target failover replica
##read -p 'Enter the primary Instance ID: ' primaryInstance
read -p 'Enter the Instance ID of the target replica: ' drInstance
read -p 'Enter the Instance ID of the target replica: ' drInstance2

#Pull all data from primary instance needed for scripting
echo "Pulling Data from your SQL instances..."
##echo $(gcloud sql instances describe $primaryInstance --format="json") > tempFiles/instanceDetails.json
echo $(gcloud sql instances describe $drInstance --format="json") > tempFiles/instanceDetails-dr.json
echo $(gcloud sql instances describe $drInstance --format="json") > tempFiles/instanceDetails-dr2.json


#ask user to confirm the action since it is irreversable
read -p 'You are attempting to failover from $primaryInstance in $primaryRegion to $drInstance in $drRegion. This is an irreversible action, please type Yes to proceed: ' acceptance
read -p 'You are attempting to failover from $primaryInstance in $primaryRegion to $drInstance2 in $drRegion. This is an irreversible action, please type Yes to proceed: ' acceptance
if [ "$acceptance" = "Yes" ]
then
    #Promote the read replica in the DR region
    echo "Promoting the replica to a standalone instance..."
    gcloud sql instances promote-replica $drInstance && gcloud sql instances promote-replica $drInstance2
   
    echo "Instance promoted."
else
    echo "You did not confirm with a Yes. No changes have been made."
fi
```

Comment: 1) You have a mistake in your script. You are using `$drInstance` twice in the `gcloud SQL instances describe` commands. 2) Would the `--async` flag accomplish your goal of running multiple commands? 3) `promote-replica` creates a stand-alone instance. Is that your goal? 4) Edit your question to clearly state the problem and objective.

Comment: I want to Promote Existing Replicas at for all replica should take as primary at time.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I asked three questions, your comment answers none of them.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry For Delay Reply
1. Actully I tried with this way but it is taking one by one command request 
2. Would the --async flag accomplish your goal of running multiple commands? = NO Idea for this 
3. promote-replica creates a stand-alone instance. Is that your goal? = no it will promote existing instance Replica to Primary 

Now What I want I don't want to enter any manual details like Instance name and all I want to promote All replia Instance to Primary using Shell Scrip it should work Parallelly not one by one is that possible in GCP using Shell ?